# UIView for drawing first two characters of the item name and code from paint code to make rectangle

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiview

I have a custom cell for my UITableView,  I will show first two characters of the item name

[image: Please select image]

so my question is how to create it and how to arrange random array value color inside the tableView cell circle.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add a label inside a view. The view will have background color randomly generated by below code

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

    var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

This can help you in the character

```
let str: String = "Hello"
str.characters.startIndex
str.characters[str.characters.startIndex]
```

Comment: but how can i use random color inside my view ??

Comment: You can set the color as background color of that view.